# How to float image next to text and stack on smaller screen

Tags: css, image, css-float, text-align, responsive

I've been working on a design that has been giving me some trouble. [This is how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8Z5C.jpg)

My code is very similar to this design but I'm not able to get it to fit properly.

I currently have it set up with a media query to scale the images down and stack under the section of text as the screen size gets smaller; however, while the window size is in the process of getting smaller, it drops the images under the text and leaves a large white space.

Additionally, at full resolution, there is a gap between the images and the text but I can't seem to get them to sit beside each other. Is there something I could be doing that will make this design easier to achieve?

```css
.redText{
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
 max-width: 400px;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 padding-left: 10%;
}
 .redText h1{
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #424242;
  padding: 45px 20px 40px 20px;
 }
 .redText h2{
  color: #d0112b;
  padding: 0px 20px 40px 20px;
  margin-top: -66px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #d0112b;
 }
 .redText p{
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #424242;
  padding: 0px 20px 110px 20px;
 }
.redMore a{
 text-decoration: none;
}

.blueText{
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
 max-width: 400px;
 display: block;
 float: right;
 padding-right: 10%
}
 .blueText h1{
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #424242;
  padding: 45px 20px 40px 20px;
 }
 .blueText h2{
  color: #0a5587;
  padding: 0px 20px 40px 20px;
  margin-top: -66px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #0a5587;
 }
 .blueText p{
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #424242;
  padding: 0px 20px 110px 20px;
 }
.blueMore a{
 text-decoration: none;
}

.space{
 float: right;
}

.wrapper{  
 overflow: hidden;
}

.redImg img{
 float: right; 
 max-width: 100%;
}
.blueImg img{
 float: left; 
 max-width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .redImg img{ 
  float: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  width: auto;   
 }
 .blueImg img{ 
  float: none;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: auto;   
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
                <div class="redText">
                 <h1>RETAIL</h1><br>
                    
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet porta libero, nec efficitur neque scelerisque at. Maecenas a ligula nec ante tincidunt pellentesque in quis libero. Nulla lorem ante, pulvinar at ultricies ut, tempor vel mi.</p><br>
                    <div style="clear: both"></div>
                    
                    <div class="redMore">
                        <a href="#"><h2>LEARN MORE<span class="space">></span></h2></a>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                
                <div class="redImg"><img src="images/work/retail.jpg"></div>
            </div>


            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="blueText">
                 <h1>INDUSTRIAL</h1><br>
                    
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet porta libero, nec efficitur neque scelerisque at. Maecenas a ligula nec ante tincidunt pellentesque in quis libero. Nulla lorem ante, pulvinar at ultricies ut, tempor vel mi.</p><br>
                    <div style="clear: both"></div>
                    
                    <div class="blueMore">
                        <a href="#"><h2>LEARN MORE<span class="space">></span></h2></a>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                
                <div class="blueImg"><img src="images/work/industrial.jpg"></div>
            </div>


            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="redText">
                 <h1>COMMERCIAL</h1><br>
                    
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet porta libero, nec efficitur neque scelerisque at. Maecenas a ligula nec ante tincidunt pellentesque in quis libero. Nulla lorem ante, pulvinar at ultricies ut, tempor vel mi.</p><br>
                    <div style="clear: both"></div>
                    
                    <div class="redMore">
                        <a href="#"><h2>LEARN MORE<span class="space">></span></h2></a>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                
                <div class="redImg"><img src="images/work/commercial.jpg"></div>
            </div>


             <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="blueText">
                 <h1>HOTELS</h1><br>
                    
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet porta libero, nec efficitur neque scelerisque at. Maecenas a ligula nec ante tincidunt pellentesque in quis libero. Nulla lorem ante, pulvinar at ultricies ut, tempor vel mi.</p><br>
                    <div style="clear: both"></div>
                    
                    <div class="blueMore">
                        <a href="#"><h2>LEARN MORE<span class="space">></span></h2></a>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                
                <div class="blueImg"><img src="images/work/hotels.jpg"></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is several way to approach your problem:

1. Use % in width of your element instead of number px: Go with 50%-50% for the block of image and the block of text, use `display:inline-block` to put them next to each other
2. Use a CSS Framework like Bootstrap or Foudation, a best example to use in your case is [media](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media)

**EDIT1**
Update with codepen: http://codepen.io/thovo/pen/EKwYpq

Comment: The first approach doesn't allow me to offset the image block and text block like in the example...or am I not understanding it properly? I'm putting a max-width of 50% on both the text and image and then displaying both as an inline-block?

Comment: did you try with bootstrap option?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with bootstrap.

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you very much The Vo